# Increasing amount of input field id by more than one

Tags: java, increment

Here is my code:

```
public void delivery(int id, int amount)
{
    stock.add(++amount, item);
}
```

I am inputting a product id and specifying how much to increase the quantity of the product by. I am currently getting an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception when I call the method. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: And what is **`stock`**?

Comment: stock is amount of Product which forms it's own class. There is an ArrayList of type product called stock

Comment: Then you should probably be iterating `stock` to find the `Product` with `id` and then altering it's *amount* through that reference. It's hard to tell exactly, because you haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: the code shown above cannot give error. Your error is in call `stock.add(int,int)`.

Comment: how would an iterator be formatted in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the method is supposed to update the stock of a product by a given amount. Let's do it step by step.

First we need a place to remember the current number of products in stock. Products are identified by an integer `id`, and for each product we associate a number indicating the current stock. Naturally we can use the `Map` interface:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> stock = new HashMap<>(); // product id -> number in stock
```

Then the `delivery` method (do you have a better name for this one?) can be:

```
public void delivery(int id, int amount) {
    stock.put(id,
              amount + stock.getOrDefault(id, 0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke. I need an Arraylist to add products to and then print product details from after updating the stock amount by calling the product id. Any ideas how I could do this?